# What does "uniquely determined" mean in a particular statement?

Tags: category-theory

> The objects of a category are in bijective correspondence with the
> identity morphisms, which are **uniquely determined** by the property
> that they serve as two-sided identities for composition. Thus, one can
> define a category to be a collection of morphisms with a
> partially-defined composition operation that has certain special
> morphisms, which are used to recognize composable pairs and which serve as two-sided identities.

I know that such expression usually means that the determined object is a function of the other, but I feel that here, there is a *logical* meaning that I'm ignoring. Because of it, I can't see how this fact implies that such an alternative definition of a category is possible.

Comment: It means that if two morphisms both have this property, then they are equal. Hence, the property "uniquely determines" the morphism.

Comment: @Thorgott In that sense, can I say that the category axioms don't distinguish between two morphisms with this property?

Comment: In a way, yes, but perhaps that's a suboptimal way of thinking about it. To say "they don't distinguish" implies that there are things that could be distinguished in some other ways and the category axioms just don't choose to do so, but it's just the case that there literally is nothing to distinguish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take it to mean that for each object, the identity morphism is the only morphism that has that property.

I.e. if for every morphism $f$ from an object to itself, one has $\iota \circ f = f = f\circ\iota$ and $\varepsilon\circ f=f = f\circ\varepsilon,$ then $\iota=\varepsilon.$

Comment: I see. On the other hand, what do you understand by partially-defined composition?

Comment: @JohnMars : A partially defined function from a set $A$ to a set $B$ is a function whose domain is some subset of $A$ (just _which_ subset may be a hard problem, and I think that's a big part of the reason why this concept exists) and whose image is a subset of $B.$ To say in this context that composition of morphisms is partially defined would mean there are some morphisms $f,g$ for which the composition $f\circ g$ is defined and some for which it is not. If $g$ is a morphism from $A$ to $B$ and $f$ is a morphism from $C$ to $D$ and $B\ne C,$ then $f\circ g$ is not defined.

Comment: $\quad\uparrow\quad$ This is like the idea of the matrix product $AB$ being defined only if the number of columns of $A$ equals the number of rows of $B. \qquad$

Comment: It looks to me as if the author of that passage is attempting to talk about categories without beginning by saying there are objects and morphisms, but rather by saying only that there are morphisms and then defining objects based on properties of morphisms.